# Cannot get the cakephp 2.3 console running on xampp on Windows 7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am running a cakePHP app which is located in *C:xammp\htdocs\scheduling*.  I am running it on xampp on Windows 7. I have added the following environment variables:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduling\app\Console\;C:\xampp\php;
```

but still cannot get the cakephp console in operation. When I navigate to *C:\xampp\htdocs\scheduling\app* and try to get the cake console or cake help, I am given a message that it is not recognized as an internal or external command.

And yes, I did reload the cmd after adding the environment variables.

Comment: Do your paths show up in `echo %PATH%`? And what command is it exactly that the CMD is complaining about, `php` or `cake`? Do you, respectively the CMD, have enough rights to access the paths and execute commands? Also how exactly are you trying to call the console?

Comment: You did too much, you should only have `C:\xampp\php;` in the path. Then call your cake shell relative to the app folder you are currently in. Everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Easy just follow the steps as mentioned below:

1. put Your PHP Path in environment Variable
2. Open Command Prompt with Admin priviliges
3. change directory to C:\xampp\htdocs\your_appname\app\console
4. Type in " Cake Bake " and run

And You Are ready to go...................Happy Baking...........................

Answer (score 0):

Just reloading the cmd is not enough, you need to either reboot your system or add it once manually before you are ready to reboot:

```
set Path="%Path%;c:\xampp\htdocs\scheduling\app\Console"
```

If all else fails, you can always call it in full from your app dir:

```
Console\cake bake
```

It's a little bit more typing, but this will work regardless of the Path variable settings.